# Ruby on Rails link_to messes up sidebar list elements alignment

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

When adding:

```
<%= link_to("Lessons",
  {:controller => 'welcome',
    :action => 'lessons'
  }) %>
```

It creates a new row on my sidebar. The link should be on the SAME line as the globe icon (globe icon is in the correct position). The other links look correct because I haven't added a ruby link to them, to show how they look without a ruby link.

Reference to navbar:
http://blog.codeply.com/2016/05/18/bootstrap-sidebar-responsive-examples/

I'm using the fixed-width responsive sidebar at the bottom of the page.

HTML Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Workspace</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>


  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>


<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Kids Typing Club</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class=""><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#about"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div><!--/.navbar -->

<div class="row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
  <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar-offcanvas">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3></h3>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a><i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg"></i>
                <%= link_to("Lessons",
                  {:controller => 'welcome',
                    :action => 'lessons'
                  }) %>  
          </a></li>
          <li><a><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i>
          Profile
          </a></li>
          <li><a><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i>
          Users
          </a></li>
          <li><a><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
          Contact
          </a></li>
          <li><a><i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg"></i>
          Help
          </a></li>


        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="visible-xs">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>
          </p>
          <h2>Fixed + Fluid Bootstrap Template with Off-canvas Sidebar</h2>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12"><div class="well"><p>Shrink the browser width to make the sidebar collapse off canvase.</p></div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well"><p>4 cols</p></div></div>
              <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well"><p>4 cols</p></div></div>
              <div class="col-md-4"><div class="well"><p>4 cols</p></div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6"><div class="well"><p>6 cols, 6 small cols</p></div></div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6"><div class="well"><p>6 cols, 6 small cols</p></div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><div class="well">4 cols, 6 small cols</div></div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><div class="well">4 cols, 6 small cols</div></div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12"><div class="well">4 cols, 12 small cols</div></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div><!--/row-offcanvas -->






<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
// Place all the styles related to the Welcome controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/

//navbar css below
body,html,.row-offcanvas {
  height:100%;
}

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#sidebar {
  width: inherit;
  min-width: 220px;
  max-width: 220px;
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
  float: left;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
#main {
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}

/*
 * off Canvas sidebar
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    width:calc(100% + 220px);
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left
  {
    left: -220px;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 0;
  }

  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
}

//navbar sidebar css ends ^





//self-created CSS:

.navbar-brand{
  color: white !important;
}

.navbar-custom{
  background-color: #5BC0DE !important;
  background: #5BC0DE !important;
}

#sidebar .active a{
  background-color: #5BC0DE !important;
}
```

Javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you @Fabrizio Bertoglio. Using the information he provided I added this css:

```
.menuitems > a:visited {
  color: #337AB7 !important;
}

.active { 
  background-color: white;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: white !important;
}
```

I added menuitems as a class to each link. This allowed my navbar-brand class rules to not be overwritten by a:visited (as it applies to all of them). Without applying the rule to specifically menuitem, my navbrand font color wouldn't change to the desired color.

Link alignment solved by @Fabrizio Bertoglio with:

```
<li><%= link_to({:controller => 'welcome',
                :action => 'lessons'
              }) do %>  
<i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg"></i> Lessons
<% end %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problems

```
<li><%= link_to({:controller => 'welcome',
                :action => 'lessons'
              }) do %>  
<i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg"></i> Lessons
<% end %>
</li>
```

Comment: I tried this and this was the result: https://gyazo.com/65fb8b21f131a5fc809b174435847ed9

Comment: @Dpet123 I updated my answer, I can not understand from that screenshot. It is not clear, If you have problems please update the question with the screenshot and the updated code you are using.

Comment: Thank you. The alignment issue was fixed, but the icons have an issue now: https://gyazo.com/5a7622f0936b47b90e30e7d7a9441d7d

Comment: The screenshot just showed that the icon became gray instead of blue.

Comment: I just used your code block. The alignment was fixed, but the globe icon (which was blue), has been changed to a faint gray color.

Comment: I just noticed, it also made changed the font of "Lessons" from blue to gray, in addition to the icon. https://gyazo.com/61c8f27ed4c723011853546e6705b817

Comment: @Dpet123 ok, go with your mouse over the icon. Right click and choose inspect element. the mozilla/chrome debugger console opens. On the right you have the css style, you can find the color or background color of that icon and change it. then you need to copy the class or set an id to the icon and fix it.

Comment: @Dpet123 did that link get the class of active like in home? I am going to sleep, usually overnight i get a lot of good idea. I suggest you to not invest time on it and just use some id or class to fix the color. thanks. bye

Comment: @Dpet123 if you check your original post, your Lesson link was already grey.

Comment: I took active off of home, and the other isn't active. I changed the a:visited element in the css, and the text is the correct color. However, now my brand  at the top left name turned blue as well. It's not reading my "navbar-brand{ color: white !important}

Comment: You're right. I didn't notice that. Adding a rails link seems to change the font color from blue to gray. Interesting.

Comment: @Dpet123 based on the bootstrap sidebar that you are using, the color of that link is set in bootstrap.css at row 1100. It is set based on the a tags and it has the following properties `a { color: #337ab7; }`, while for the active first class. It is a class `.active { background-color: #337ab7;}`